# Why is default authentication schema not used unless specified explicitly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4

This is how I set the default scheme:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication();
```

If I use this on my controller it works:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemas = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

But if I replace it with just `[Authorize]` the response becomes `Unauthorized`. I expect `[Authorize]` to work the same because the scheme is already set as default.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you share the complete code in your `Startup.ConfigureServices`?